# Recursive ->toArray() for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Laravel as an API an AngularJS front end.  Part of this is when the app loads I preload the app with the user signed in to save an http request.

Is there an recursive `->toArray()` that will loop through all properties and convert all eloquent models to jsonable arrays?

I have made one manually in L3 but have not found something similar in the docs.

PortalController.php
`$user->medications` is an array of eloquent objects.

**Does not work**

```
<?php

class PortalController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->healthProfile = $user->getHealthProfile();
        $user->medications = $user->getItems('medication');

        return View::make('portal.index', [
            'init' => [
                             // The array of medications disappear.
                'user' => $user->toArray()
            ]
        ]);
    }

}
```

**Works**

```
<?php

class PortalController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->healthProfile = $user->getHealthProfile();
        $user->medications = $user->getItems('medication')->toArray(); //boop

        return View::make('portal.index', [
            'init' => [
                            // The array of medications still exists.
                'user' => $user->toArray()
            ]
        ]);
    }

}
```

views/portal/index.blade.php

```
<script>
    (function() {

        'use strict';

        angular.module('portal.init', [])

            .service('Init', [function() {
                return function() {
                    return {{ json_encode($init) }};
                }
            }]);

    })();
</script>
```

My L3 class that converts recursively, hoping there is a native solution.

```
    public static function to_array($models)
    {
        if ($models instanceof Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model) {
            $models = $models->to_array();
        }

        if (is_array($models)) {
            foreach ($models as $key => $value) {
                $models[$key] = self::to_array($value);
            }
        }

        return $models;
    }
```

## Update

// models/User.php

```
    // ..etc.

public function allergies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PortalItem', 'portal_user_id')
        ->whereKey('allergy');
}

public function medications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PortalItem', 'portal_user_id')
        ->whereKey('medication');
}

public function symptoms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PortalItem', 'portal_user_id')
        ->whereKey('symptom');
}

    // ..etc.
```

// controllers/PortalController.php

```
<?php

class PortalController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $user = User::with('healthProfile', 'medications', 'allergies', 'symptoms', 'procedures', 'immunizations')
            ->whereId(Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();

        return View::make('portal.index', [
            'init' => [
                'user' => $user->toArray()
            ]
        ]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just use the native [toJson() method on the eloquent class](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json)?

```
$user->toJson();
```

so in your controller it would be

```
 return View::make('portal.index', [
        'init' => [
                         // The array of medications disappear.
            'user' => $user->toJson()
        ]
    ]);
```

If you want medications included in the JSON conversion - you must first eager load them.

```
$user = User::with('medications')->all();
```

Comment: I still get `"medications":{}` and I need to convert the whole `$init` var to json.  When I do that it tries to echo an array and you get the Array to string conversion error.

Comment: Thats because you need to eager load the relationship first

Comment: Idk if I did this correctly but I'm eager loading them now from a key-value style table in MySQL (I have no idea what these might look like the in future)

Answer (score 1):

Surely `healthProfile` and `medications` could be made into relationships?

If you do this, you can then do something like this.

```
class PortalController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        // No need to create a new query for something we already have
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->load('healthProfile', 'medications');

        return View::make('portal.index', [
            'init' => [
                'user' => $user->toArray()
            ]
        ]);
    }

}
```

Then simply, in the template (I assume you're using blade), you would just do:

```
{{ json_encode($init) }}
```

The assumption here is that you're actually using the php/blade variable to prepopulate a variable within javascript, or at least, have it output.

There is the `toJson()` method provided by laravel, but that doesn't suit your needs here. Try setting up the relationships and using `json_encode()` in the blade/template file, and that should work. Any other questions, let me know.

Hope that helps.